OneNote note>section>page Layout in separate panel. Hierarchical panel
I have been using the "OneNote for Windows 10" app and the layout of the app is as follows

Now using the OneNote app (which is I believe OneNote Microsoft 365 app) I get the following layout

Note how the sections dont have its own separate panel.I want a hierarchical panel. How can I get the same layout as the windows 10 app in OneNote 365.
Thanks
